# Consume k8s configmap in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

I've got a spring boot service that presently uses `.properties` file for consuming variables using the spring @Value annotation. Recently we have been migrating the spring boot service to K8 cluster. This means that, we need to create a `configmap.yml` file containing all the same properties as the `.properties` file. And whenever changes to properties are made, it must be done in both places, the configmap and `.properties` file used for local dev. So we have to manage 2 files (configmap and .properties) for each spring profile. Is there a better way to do this? We use gitlab ci/cd tools for deployment.

Is there a way to use the configmap instead of the properties for local development in our machines, so that we can discard the .properties file altogether and only maintain configmap?

What's the ideal way to manage properties for the spring boot application?

Sample service-config-map.yaml

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: myservice-config
data:
  server.port: "10300"
  spring.application.name: myserviceGateway
  myservice.application.name: helloworld
  myservice.server.apiContext: /api
  myservice.server.versionContext: /v
  myservice.current.version=2.0
```

properties file `application.properties`

```
server.port=10300
spring.application.name=myserviceGateway
myservice.application.name=helloworld
myservice.server.apiContext=/api
myservice.server.versionContext=/v
myservice.current.version=2.0
```

Comment: can you post example of configmap.yaml and application.properties?

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Cloud Kubernetes project](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/html/) makes Kubernetes `ConfigMap`s available during application bootstrapping and triggers hot reloading of beans or Spring context when changes are detected on observed `ConfigMap`s.

An example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples/kubernetes-reload-example)

The bootstrap yaml which has the name of the config map looks like

```
spring:
  application:
    name: reload-example
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 5000
      config:
        sources:
          - name: other
          - name: ${spring.application.name}
```

Comment: I don't think I got my concern out correctly. I'm able to use the `ConfigMap` in my spring boot application on kubernetes perfectly fine. I would like to be able to use the same `ConfigMap` for my local development on my local machine as well. Right now I'm using a separate `application.properties` file for all of my local testing and development.

Comment: That's not possible...you should have different profile for local and kube..in local profile use application.properties and in kube profile use ConfigMap

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable.

First of all you would need a bean to placehold from yaml like:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource(CONF_FILE));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

And then you can annotate any your standard service as:

```
    @Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="service-config-map")
public class ConfigMapConfigService {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your type of access to the cluster, you can use the K8s API to retrieve resources via HTTP.
For example, you can have some sort of a script that pulls the configmap from your cluster and parses it to yaml (it's in json by default, not sure if yaml output is supported, haven't really tested, though).

See more here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.ConfigMap.html#Get-api-v1-namespaces-namespace-configmaps-name